# Handling remote push notifications from multiple servers

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, ngcordova

Within Cordova, 
would like to handle push notifications coming from 2 different servers, one would be from the *Marketing area*, containing promotions and offers, and the second would be from our own server, (*Developer area*) where push notifications would contain a different set of possible actions.

I understand that registering to APN and GCM only happens once per device & app, so is there a way i could handle differently depending on the server they come from?

The client is built with Ionic.

Comment: I don't understand the question - the different pushes have different payloads, therefore the app can know which push it has received according to what the payload is and therefore it can handle them differently. What did I miss about your question?

Comment: Actually, that's it. After further reading, it all comes down to what the payload contains. Could you please post this as an answer so i can vote you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question - the different pushes have different payloads, therefore the app can know which push it has received according to what the payload is and therefore it can handle them differently. What did I miss about your question?